# How to convert primitive.M to map [string]string then to string?

Tags: string, mongodb, dictionary, go

How can we convert primitive M to string?

```golang
package main

import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func main() {
    a := bson.M{ // primitive.M
        "test": bson.M{
            "fielda": "AAA",
            "fieldb": "BBB",
        },
    }
}
```

I'm using this to log mongodb documents that are failing in process.
I was able to print the value using `logrus.Error`, I want to replicate this convert to string and then log it to file.

```golang
// cursor = "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo" *mongo.Cursor
// logrus = "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
//...
        var temp bson.M
        _ := cursor.Decode(&temp)     // assume this is not returning error, it will log the map
        logrus.Error("value: ", temp) // value: map[__v:0 _id:ObjectID(\"5c8ef7df7216e9935ecd7859\") field1:test]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution could be to use [`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint) like this:

```
a := bson.M{
    "_id": primitive.NewObjectID(),
    "test": bson.M{
        "fielda": "AAA",
        "fieldb": "BBB",
    },
}

s := fmt.Sprint(a)
fmt.Println(s)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4CKIdkH60G-)):

```
map[_id:ObjectID("4af9f07018f18fbf63f00366") test:map[fielda:AAA fieldb:BBB]]
```